# What's the difference between sfdx-lwc-jest & lwc/jest-preset?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I'm trying to set up Jest for LWC. I have looked at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_jest_installation) and I have looked at the [LWC website](https://lwc.dev/guide/test#install-jest). Both of them refer to different packages for Jest installation. Which one should I use? and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per my understanding after reading the docs,

### sfdx-lwc-jest

1. sfdx-lwc-jest works in Salesforce DX projects only.
2. sfdx-lwc-jest, sets up all the necessary Jest configurations for a Salesforce DX project.

### lwc/jest-preset

According to [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lwc/jest-preset), Tools to assist with testing Lightning Web Components (LWC) with Jest. This project provides 2 services: preset Jest configuration for testing Lightning web components, and stubs for common external libraries used in Lightning web components.

> After reading [this](https://www.mattgoldspink.co.uk/testing-lightning-web-components/) Blog, **@salesforce/lwc-jest** is wrapper
>   command of **@lwc/jest-preset** **@lwc/module-resolver**
>   **@lwc/compiler** **@lwc/engine** .